# Save/Load High Score After Termination in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

I've been experimenting trying to get my highscore to save or when the app terminates and reopens in displays the previous highscore. I'm using NSUserDefaults, but haven't had much luck. Here is my code.

This is used to get/set the high score:

```
-(NSInteger)setHighScore {


highScore = self.score;
key = @"highScore" ;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highScore forKey:key];

return highScore;
}


-(NSInteger)getPreviousHighScore {


highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:key];

return highScore; }
```

Both the NSInteger "highScore" and string "key" are static and properly declared at the beginning of the class.

```
static NSInteger highScore;
static NSString *key = @"highScore";
```

In my didMoveToView I have a label to test the getting of the previous high score... This is the code for that.

```
SKLabelNode *label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [self getPreviousHighScore]];
label.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
label.fontColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self addChild:label];
```

And then finally, in my AppDelegate.m I have this:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

After all this my label just shows a 0 every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you paste the code about __NSInteger "highScore" and string "key" are static and properly declared at the beginning of the class__? I think there may be the problem.

Comment: What's the problem? It's very nice to post your solution as the answer:]

Comment: Have you checked the value of self.score before setting the high score?

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean I solved it, I meant I posted the static integers. @ChildhoodAndy

Comment: Where in `AppDelegate.m` do you call the synchronize method? Can you try making `setHighScore` an NSNotification and use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"setScore" object:nil];` in the `AppDelegate.m`?

Comment: In -applicationWillTerminate @Andriko13